# SvelteKit alternative way to display component base on screen width

Tags: typescript, frontend, sveltekit

I use this to get the current window size in my sveltekit app, and change the component being displayed when the width is small:

```
<script>
let size;
</script>
<svelte:window bind:innerwidth{size}/>
<div>
    {#if size > 768}
        <TableDisplay/>
    {:else}
        <CardsDisplay/>
    {/if}
</div>
```

Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: CSS media query? By the way, what's wrong with your current implementation?

Answer (score 2):

[Media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_media_queries/Using_media_queries) would be an option.

You would define classes that show/hide an element depending on viewport width. This requires a wrapper element that the style can be applied to, or you define the rules as global, pass the class into the components and add them there.

E.g.

```html
<div class="show-large">
    <TableDisplay/>
</div>
<div class="show-small">
    <CardsDisplay/>
</div>

<style>
  /* `contents` prevents wrapper from affecting layout */
  .show-small { display: none; }
  .show-large { display: contents; }

  @media (max-width: 768px) {
    .show-small { display: contents; }
    .show-large { display: none; }
  }
</style>
```

[REPL Example](https://svelte.dev/repl/ea254bc5b01346348823f2e936e558e5?version=4.0.5)

Note that this does behave differently from the `{#if}` approach:
With media queries, all elements and components are created and inserted into the document, just not always shown, while `{#if}` does not create anything if the condition is not met.